# Delta method for vector valued functions

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, delta-method

Suppose I have an estimator $B\in\mathbb{R}^m$ converging to $\beta$, such that
$$
\sqrt{n}(B-\beta)\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma).
$$

I am interested in a quantity $\mathbf{h}(B):\ \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$, and would like to use delta method to approximate the asymptotic distribution.

Let $\nabla\mathbf{h}(\beta)$ be a matrix $\left[\frac{\partial h_k(\beta)}{\partial \beta_j}\right]_{jk}$. When $p=1$, multivariate Delta method would provide
$$
\sqrt{n}(\mathbf{h}(B)-\mathbf{h}(\beta))\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(0,\nabla\mathbf{h}(\beta)^T\cdot\Sigma\cdot\nabla\mathbf{h}(\beta)).
$$
Can we say that it is the same for the case when $p>1$?
When I actually tried this numerically, I find that the covariance $\nabla\mathbf{h}(\beta)^T\cdot\Sigma\cdot\nabla\mathbf{h}(\beta)$ is not invertible.

Comment: not invertible is OK, given it is positive semidefined.

Comment: I think I found the problem. My $\mathbf{h}$ is a function whose image is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$, and probably that is why the covariance is singular.

Comment: If you can give out $h$ function, it will be easy for discussion. Another posibility is $\Sigma$ itself is singular.